# why doesn't byte flip involve a simple reversal of order

Tags: assembly, hex, byte, endianness

On the programming calculator I am using, the hex value `0x803F` gets turned into `3F80` when I hit the "byte flip" button. However, I would have expected `0x803F` to become `0xF308` i.e. a simple reversal of order. Why doesn't a byte flip involve a simple reversal of order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are thinking that the bits should be reverse but endianness refers to the bytes not the bits. 0x803f represents two bytes, the first is 80 and the second is 3F. So reversing the endianness causes the value to become 0x3F80

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Big-endian

Comment: bitwise reversal would change 0x3F to 0xFC.  (`0b00111111` to `0b11111100`).  The OP's brainfart is expecting the nibbles (hex digits) to be reversed.